# Basic GUI application Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin

How do I extend the following program to display basic GUI element Button in Cygwin on Windows?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

And to compile and run.

```
gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
./hello.exe
```

Comment: Wouldn't this question (which is not related to Unix) better asked on StackOverflow or Programmer?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Cygwin is technically unix although you are right it is more about c then unix.  I have not tried this question  on SO, but I feel like it might be closed or more likely put on hold for being either being to broad or narrow.  SO is often a little more stringent on questions but I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that without some specific GUI library, since *standard* C99 or C11 does not define any.

BTW, you should compile with `gcc -Wall -g hello.c -o hello.exe` ; you really want all warnings and debug info.

You might consider using some cross-platform GUI library [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) or [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/) or (in C++) [Qt](http://qt.io/). You'll need to install it before using it and of course pass additional arguments to `gcc` (several `-I` directives before the source file, several `-L` directives and `-l` libraries from high-level to low-level). Notice that order of arguments to `gcc` is important. You may want to use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make) as your builder, with your own `Makefile` ...

<sup>(I don't know Windows and I recommend Linux; perhaps some system provided Windows GUI library is usable from Cygwin)</sup>

Your program will then become event-driven, with the [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) usually provided by the GUI library. It will become much more complex.

You could (instead of a desktop GUI approach) consider making your program some specialized Web server; you'll then use some HTTP server library (I know about [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), but it probably has not been ported to Windows), and your program would become a Web application usable thru a browser, and should also be event-driven.

Comment: you might want to conside targeting mingw instead of cygwin.